# mosquitto_sub fails with "Error: Problem setting TLS options: File not found." when using certificate files on xubuntu 20.02

Tags: ubuntu, mosquitto

I have a weird problem with mosquitto_sub 1.6.14 running on xubuntu 20.02.
Everything works fine as long as I don't use certificate files.
When using certificate files, I am getting "Error: Problem setting TLS options: File not found." every time.
I am using the following commandline:

```
mosquitto_sub -h test.mosquitto.org -p 8884 -t tengo/bravo --cafile ~/test/mosquitto.org.crt --cert ~/test/returned.crt --key ~/test/client.key
```

When using the same command line with the same files on a fedora33 machine, everything works fine.

Can anybody help me? Please!

Comment: And all the files exist in the locations specified and are readable by the user running the command?

Comment: Hi hardlib, thank you for your response. Yes, the files are in the proper location and they are reachable. I tried every kind of absolute/relative path with/without quotes/doublequotes, with/without sudo ... which I was able to imagine.

Comment: pre-pend the command with `strace` to see if you can work out which file it's trying to find

Comment: Hi hardlib, thank you for the hint to use strace. Somewhere in the trace I found a line, which looks similar to my command-line, but the option "--cafile" is followed by a filename without any path. The options for the other files are followed with full paths and filenames. So the problem seems to be at the --cafile.

Comment: I ran into this and my issue was using relative file paths. THat's a no-no

Answer (score 3):

The root-cause of the problem seems to be the installation via snap. I followed the primary suggestion on https://mosquitto.org/download/ to install via snap, having the mentioned problems.

I found a post in ask-ubuntu where someone had a similar problem, where mosquito worked initially after installing with apt, but did not work anymore when reinstalling with snap.

So I tried to remove the snap installation and followed the secondary installation hints on https://mosquitto.org/download/ to install via apt.

Surprise surprise ... now it works.

Comment: This is most likely an apparmour/selinux attribute problem with the snap executables.

Answer (score 1):

You should manually connect the mosquitto:home plug to snapd home slot, using below command.

```
sudo snap connect mosquitto:home snapd:home
```

Answer (score 0):

For me when this error shows up, the problem usually is that I do not have read access to any one of the --cafile, --cert or --key files. Sometimes I have scripts that generate these files in a docker container, with a mounted drive and permissions don't align.

This error is returned when any of these files couldn't be opened. Have a look at the source code here:

https://github.com/eclipse/mosquitto/blob/master/apps/mosquitto_ctrl/options.c#L599
https://github.com/eclipse/mosquitto/blob/master/lib/options.c#L128